# Why isn't $\ln|ax|+C$ the anti-derivative of $\frac1x$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

If
$$\frac{d}{dx} (\ln|ax|)=\frac1x$$
then why isn't the antiderivative of $1/x$ equal to $\ln|ax| + C$, but instead just $\ln|x| + C$?

Comment: $\ln(|a||x|)+c=\ln|x|+\ln|a|+c=\ln|x|+C$

Comment: Becausw $\ln|ax|=\ln|a|+\ln|x|$ and $\ln|a|$ is a ... ?

Comment: Notice that $ln(|ax|)+C=ln(|a|)+ln(|x|)+C$ and $ln(|a|)+C$ is a constant. Then $ln(|ax|)+C=ln(|x|)+C'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is. Just notice that

$$\ln\lvert ax\rvert=\ln\lvert a\rvert\lvert x\rvert=\ln\lvert x\rvert+\ln\lvert a\rvert,$$

and so

$$\ln\lvert ax\rvert+C=\ln\lvert x\rvert+D,$$

where we set $D=C+\ln\lvert a\rvert$, and as the constants can be **any** real number (with the exception that $a$ cannot be zero for obvious reasons), this is perfectly fine, and encompasses all antiderivatives.